# window.onload with Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Attempting to get a h1 to fade-in once the page loads. It works in all browsers when testing locally. But when hosted, with Chrome, it doesn't always fade-in. Sometimes it's just fully visible right from the start. I've tried 2 methods that both seem to work in Safari and Firefox, but Chrome is an "iffy" whether it works or not.

Is Chrome just loading from cache, without executing, or is there another method of writing this JavaScript?

I've tried:

```
$('.headerTopHeading, .headerSubHeading').animate({
    'opacity': '1'}, 1200);
```

Wrapped in a document.ready, and setting the Opacity to zero via CSS from the start.

And I've tried:

```
window.onload = function () {
    $('.headerTopHeading, .headerSubHeading').fadeIn('1200');
};
```

Setting the display to none via CSS and placed outside the document.ready wrap.

Any suggestions? Or reason why Chrome doesn't behave consistently all the time?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there are no errors in the JS console that sometimes stop the script to be executed?

I suggest you try to use jQuery only to change the class and leave the animation to CSS. Although the code

```
$('.headerTopHeading, .headerSubHeading').animate({
    'opacity': '1'}, 1200);
```

looks fine, so maybe try wrapping it in your

```
  window.onload = function () {
  }
```

statement?

Comment: No errors. I even put a "console.log" inside the "window.onload" and it comes through as expected. I did find in the JQuery documentation that apparently it will sometimes fail to fire if the objects are in cache.

Answer (score 0):

why not simply use css animation to control the title fade in simply add the default property of opacity: 0  with a animation-delay of how long after the page has loaded you would like the fade-in to happen

```
@keyframes fadein {
   0% {opacity:0;}
   100% {opacity: 1;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    0% {opacity:0;}
    100% {opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes fadein {
   0% {opacity:0;}
   100% {opacity: 1;}
}

.fade-title {
   opacity: 0;
   color: #5f5f5f;
   -webkit-animation:fadein ease-in 1;
   -moz-animation:fadein ease-in 1;
   animation:fadein ease-in 1;

   animation-delay: 2s;
   -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards; 
   -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
   animation-fill-mode:forwards;

   -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
   -moz-animation-duration:1s;
   animation-duration:1s;
}
```

example: 
http://codepen.io/shperber/pen/XKzOLX

Comment: I considered this approach, and it does seem to be the best fail-proof option. I just didn't like having to set a timer on it. But wait, would using the css keyframes method only fire after the page has loaded, or after just the css file has loaded?

Comment: I just tried this approach, and while it does fade-in as expected, I still face the same issue with Chrome where if the page has been cached, it will not fade-in and just appear. It's definitely a way Chrome is handling cached objects.

Comment: what about moving the fade in animation to a different class then adding it after page load: 
$('.fade-title').addClass('fade-in')